# 2 pseudo selectors didn't work respectively in CSS #id:after:active{}

Tags: css

I need to click on the car wheel , so the car advance 100px ,, the wheel in this case is "after" , but the transition is not working with ":after:active" selectors but it does with other selectors . how can I correct this ?

PS: I'm using chrome.

```
#Car{
height: 30%;
width: 30%;
background-color: blue;
position:relative;
bottom:20%;
left: 30%;
top:-40%;
border-top-right-radius : 20% 30%;
border-bottom-right-radius : 20% 30%;}

 #Car:after{
 content:"";
 height: 50%;
 width: 20%;
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 top:90%;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background: #cc7b0f;
 border: 10px solid grey;
 z-index:6;
 }

 #Car:after:active{
 transform: translate(100px, 0px);
 transition:ease-in-out;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what means your selector `Car:after:active` is

```
:after element that is :active should have rules{*translate*}
```

but what you need here is

```
#Car that is :active has :after element which should have rules{*translate*}
```

so you should change your selector to

```
#Car:active:after
```

Comment: Just one problem, only the wheel has moved , not the whole car

Comment: can you please create a code snippet for that and add full html/css you're using?

Comment: Here you go Im allowed to use only CSS and HTML for this interface , I'm not sure it's possible to move the whole car with CSS only :/ , is there any way? https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxBbvwyrtSapX0xOektFUXN2cVU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: sure, remove rules for #car:active:after and #car:active:before and add #car:active{transform: translate(100px)} so you translating the whole car(not just wheels which are :before and :after) also you might want translate the smoke in the same way

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo elements must come last, ie:

```
#Car:active:after
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s1krLby1/